# How to convert a long data type to an int data type in PySpark?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

Whenever I try to convert a long datatype in Pyspark to an int data type in Pyspark, I get an arithmetic overflow.

What I do is

df.withColumn("column", F.col("column").cast(IntegerType()))

But I get error message saying: "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int"

Comment: Provide sample dataset

Comment: And also the version of spark that you are using.